# PropTypes are always wrong

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

App component - set data from data.json, send props to children components:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import { HeaderPanel, PostsPanel } from './index';

import './app.scss';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            userData: Object,
            infoData: Object,
            postsData: Object
       };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('./data.json') 
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ 
                    userData: res.data.userData,
                    infoData: res.data.infoData,
                    postsData: res.data.posts
                });  
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app">
                <div>
                    <HeaderPanel
                        userData={this.state.userData}
                        infoData={this.state.infoData}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="posts">
                    <PostsPanel postsData={this.state.postsData} />
                </div>            
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

First-child, divide props to approporiate components, give me the error too:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import {ModalContainer, ModalDialog} from 'react-modal-dialog';

import { TopFunctionPanel, TopDisplayData } from './topPanel';
import { MiddleFunctionPanel, MiddleDisplayData } from './middlePanel';

import './headerPanel.scss';

export default class HeaderPanel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            avatar: Object,
            user: String,
            city: String,
            country: String,
            like: Number,
            following: Number,
            followers: Number,
            isOpen: false
        };

        this.setLike = this.setLike.bind(this);
        this.setFollowers = this.setFollowers.bind(this);
        this.toggleModalWindow = this.toggleModalWindow.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
           this.setState({
                avatar : props.userData.avatar,
                user: props.userData.user,
                city: props.userData.city,
                country: props.userData.country,
                like : props.infoData.like,
                following: props.infoData.following,
                followers: props.infoData.followers,
            });
     }

    setLike(val) {
        this.setState({like: val});
    }

    setFollowers(val) {
        this.setState({followers: val});
    }

    toggleModalWindow() {
        this.setState({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="headerPanel">
          {
                this.state.isOpen &&
                <ModalContainer onClose={this.toggleModalWindow}>
                  <ModalDialog onClose={this.toggleModalWindow}>
                            <div className="modal">
                                <div> 
                                    <div><h1>You share:</h1></div>
                                </div>
                                <p>{window.location.href}</p>
                            </div>
                  </ModalDialog>
                </ModalContainer>
              }
                <TopFunctionPanel
                    setLike={this.setLike}
                    like={this.state.like}
                    toggleModalWindow={this.toggleModalWindow}
                />
                <TopDisplayData
                    avatar={this.state.avatar}
                    user={this.state.user}
                    city={this.state.city}
                    country={this.state.country}
                />
                <MiddleDisplayData
                    like={this.state.like}
                    following={this.state.following}
                    followers={this.state.followers}
                />
               <MiddleFunctionPanel
                    setFollowers={this.setFollowers}
                    followers={this.state.followers}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

HeaderPanel.propTypes = {
    userData: PropTypes.object,
    infoData: PropTypes.object
};
```

And grand-child. They give me this strange error too

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import './middlePanel.scss';

const DisplayData = ({ like, following, followers }) => {

    return (
        <div className="middleDisplayData">
            <div>
                <p>{like}</p>
                <p>Liks</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>{following}</p>
                <p>Following</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>{followers}</p>
                <p>Followers</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default DisplayData;

DisplayData.propTypes = {
    like: PropTypes.number,
    following: PropTypes.number,
    followers: PropTypes.number
};
```

And I have a warning (`console` and `jest` gave me this):

> warning.js:35 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `like` of type `function` supplied to `DisplayData`, expected `number`.
>       in DisplayData (created by HeaderPanel)
>       in HeaderPanel (created by App)
>       in div (created by App)
>       in div (created by App)
>       in App

I don't get it. My `propTypes` should be number (in grand-child component). But even if I change it to `func`, I have warning that it should be number. I know that with `func` I should to use `.isRequire` because of `undefined`, but here? I even have no idea what is wrong. I saw similar topics, but they's about `func` `prop` type (and as I understood adding `.isRequire` will help me) or some wrong spelling.

Comment: It may be because you're not extending React.Component but creating a plain JS object?

Comment: You should how us how you are rendering the component and which props you pass into it.

Comment: This looks explicit and straight forward error. Somewhere you are  using ```< DisplayData />``` and you are passing the wrong props to the component. Can you triple check this?

Answer (score 0):

I updated my questione.

Hmm, it strange, but it looks like everything is ok. It looks like during sending props from one component to second they change they type. After render they are function and then consola show this warning. But in the end they change to number so, everything is ok.

[image]